# Same material different results on two models in Blender

Tags: textures, blender, uv-mapping, materials

Good afternoon, I am trying to texturize in the same way two figures that I have downloaded in .gltf format. I have applied exactly the same material with the same nodes to both figures but the result is very different, one of them is very smooth.

What can be happening?

Below I attach the images of the normals of both figures, the nodes I have applied and the result of both.

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnVMi.png)
[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS8xK.png)

[Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY9eb.png)

[Results figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRNVg.png)
[Results figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X672W.png)

I tried to apply same material to other models I have downloaded and they work as expected (Figure 1)

Thanks!